# Create a html file and upload it to some server with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a sample HTML content string:

```
const HTMLTEMPLATE = `
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/static-for-dev/favicon.png">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>Test</div>
    </body>
  </html>
`;
```

I use this string to generate a HTML file with `fs.writeFile()` method:

```
fs.writeFile('sample.html', HTMLTEMPLATE, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  console.log('The file has been saved!');
});
```

My question is, Is there some way that I can retrieve the file after `fs.writeFile()` complete and upload it to some other server (maybe some cloud storage server) with Node.js?

Comment: you mean that want want to move this file to some other location on the same server ? or onto some other server ?

Comment: onto some other server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the [**scp**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scp) module and include it in your code like this,

```
var scp = require('scp');
```

To read the `sample.html` that you have created and to upload it to the server, you can try the following,

```
var options = {
  file: 'sample.html',
  user: 'username',
  host: 'myServer',
  port: '22',
  path: '~'
}

fs.readdir('./uploads', function(err, files) {
    var fileExists = true;
        files.forEach(function(file) {
        if(file=="sample.html") {
            scp.send(options, function (err) {
                if (err) 
                    console.log(err);
                else 
                    console.log('File transferred.');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!